# Flutter Google SignIn not showing

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

in my app I just want that users can sign In normally with email and password AND with Google. But when I log in with google I will be redirected to the home page there should be then my google username and email and also my photo. But I get the error :

The getter 'displayName' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: displayName

```
 GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
```

```
 Center(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getUserInfo(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.data()["Username"] :  _googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                                  fontSize: 35.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.data()["Email"] : _googleSignIn.currentUser.email,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                          );
                        });
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                    return Text("No data");
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),
                  );

                },
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is complaining about this line:

```
title: Text(snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.data()["Username"] :  _googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName,
```

If `_googleSignIn.currentUser` is null, then it would cause an error trying to use `displayName`.  You should check `currentUser` for null (make sure a user is actually signed in) before trying to use it.